# how to show the content in many line of database one field value

Tags: jsp, struts2

i want to display the value in many line of one field of table and separation will be add with the any special mark.when the special mark got then iterator will generate the new line for new content and so on until the data end this is **for jsp view**

value of data field:

```
8/11/2011<\r\n> •  Bhopal-10 Years<br/> • Bhopal -09 Years<br/>
```

wanted out put

```
 From 8/11/2011
• Bhopal-10 Years

• Bhopal -09 Years
```

this "db.div_info" have the whole paragraph and want to display in many line

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but it looks like a normal string split operation and list/array iteration on the JSP side. What's the actual problem? Splitting, or iterating?

Comment: the problem is splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can call String `split` method in Struts2 tags e.g. in `<s:iterator>` tag and split your value with this pattern `<br/>|<\r\n>`.

```
<s:iterator value="your_value.split('<br/>|<\r\n>')">
  <s:property/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display in HTML, then use this sort of code in JSP:

```
<%="8/11/2011"> // Replace the string by a dynamic variable you use.
<br/>
<ul>
    <li>Bhopal-10 Years</li>
    <li> Bhopal -09 Years</li>
</ul>.
```